# Laravel add an extra can:isSuperAdmin middleware in my route

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
    Route::group([
    'middleware' =>['JwtMiddleware', 'auth:api','can:isSuperAdmin'],
    'prefix' => '/schools'
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [SchoolController::class, 'index']);
});
```

I want to add an extra authentication like only the user who has super_admin role can only access this end point, the user_id of user who has super_admin role is 1 . how do i can add middleware to my route just like above..
what is the other relations/important codes to work this middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a middleware under your middleware folder:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class EnsureUserHasRole
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            // Redirect...
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And register this middleware to your `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // ...
       'role' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureUserHasRole::class,
    ];
```

You will also need `hasRole()` in your User model:

```
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        switch ($role) {
            case 'isSuperAdmin':
                return $this->super_admin;
        }
    }
```

After all you can use it as:

```
Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['JwtMiddleware', 'auth:api', 'role:isSuperAdmin'],
            'prefix' => '/schools'
        ], function () {
            Route::get('/', [SchoolController::class, 'index']);
        });
```